# Simple Projection Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $V = U \oplus W$, and define $P_{U,W} \in L(V)$ where $P_{U,W}$ denotes the projection onto $U$ with null space $W$. I am trying to verify three properties and would like some feedback and help.

> 1. $P_{U,W}v =v \iff v \in U$

Let $v \in U$, then $v = P_{U,W} x$ for **all** $x \in V$. So we let $x = v$

**EDIT 1** figured out

On the hand $P_{U,W}v =v \implies P_{U,W}v \in U$ by def of $P_{U,W}v$. But $P_{U,W}v = v$, so $v \in U$.

> 1. $R(P_{U,W}) = U$

So $R(P_{U,W}) = \{P_{U,W}x : x \in V \}$ and let $y \in R(P_{U,W}) \implies y = P_{U,W}x \in U$ for **all** $x \in V$, but that must mean $y \in R(P_{U,W})$

**EDIT** 2 figured out

> 1. $N(P_{U,W}) = W$

let $x \in N(P_{U,W}) =\{x : P_{U,W} x = 0\} \implies P_{U,W} x= 0 \in W$ since $W$ is a subspace.

Let $x \in W$, then $w = v - P_{U,W}v \implies P_{U,W}w = P_{U,W}v - P_{U,W}P_{U,W}v = 0\in N(P_{U,W})$

**EDIT** Solved, though I feel there is a more elementary method. Please give me some feedback on all the questions

Comment: I don't understand what's troubling you. Image of $P_{U,W}$ is, by definition, $U$. If $v = P_{U,W} v \in \mathop{\rm Im} P_{U,W}$, then $v \in \mathop{\rm Im} P_{U,W} = U$.

Comment: Sorry, I am editing as I go. I think I solved 1 and 2. I am going to try $3$

Comment: If it's not an orthogonal projection, you don't need (nor necessarily have) orthogonality of $U$ and $V$. Do you still need a help with the kernel?

Comment: It is not the orthogonal projection. I still need help with (3) I think (assuming I did 1 and 2 right)

Comment: Hint: $V = U \oplus W$ is a direct sum. That means that for each $v \in V$ there re unique $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v = u + w$. Does that help?

Comment: Uhh the book states $v = P_{U,W}v + P_{W,U}v$ where $P_{U,W}v \in U$ and $P_{W,U} v \in W$. I am working with $P_{U,W}v$, so I am not sure how that helps.

Comment: What you wrote is also true. That's how you find $u$ and $w$ I wrote about.

Comment: The only information I can extract from your hint is $w = v - P_{U,W}v \implies P_{U,W}w = P_{U,W}v - P_{U,W}P_{U,W}v = 0 \implies P_{U,W}w \in N(P_{U,W})$. But I believe there is a more elementary method.

Comment: That's O.K. I don't think you can have a "more elementary" method, since - for this to work - you need both properties ($V$ being a direct sum and $P$ being a projection defined by its components).

Comment: Did I do the others right? I especially bolded some words in (1) and (2). Please harshly critic them.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense that $v = P_{U,W}x$ for all $x \in V$. That would mean that for all $x \in V$, $x = v$, so $V$ has only one element and, since $V$ is a vector space, that element must be the zero vector, hence $V = \{0\}$.

Comment: The problem with your question is that it's hard to discern what can be used. How do you define projection? Usually, things you're trying to prove are part of the definition. So, if you want a detailed answer, you must provide all that is known for $P$. For example, you say that $P$ is a projection unto $U$ with the kernel $W$, and then you go on proving exactly that $U$ is the image and $W$ is the kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Pick $v\in V$. You can write this *uniquely* as $u+w$ with $u\in U,w\in W$. You're defining $P$ by $P(v)=P(u+w)=u$, the projection onto $U$.

Then it follows $$(i)\;\;\operatorname{im} P=U$$  $$(ii)\;\;\operatorname{ker} P=W$$

$(i)$ Pick $u\in U$. Then $P(u)=u$ so $u\in \operatorname{im} P$. Conversely, if $v\in\operatorname{im} P$ we have that $P(x)=v$ for some $x\in V$. But we can write $x=u+w$ uniquely with $u\in U,w\in W$ so that $P(u+w)=u=v$. So $v\in U$.

$(ii)$ If $w\in W$ then we can write $w=0+w$ with $0\in U,w\in W$ so $$P(w)=P(0+w)=0$$ and $w\in \operatorname{ker}P$. Converesely if $P(v)=0$ write $v=u+w$ with $u\in U,w\in W$. Then $P(v)=P(u+w)=u=0$. Thus $u=0$, $v=w$ and $v\in W$.